# Eclipse: Solve "No end tag" Warnings When Tags Span Files?

Tags: html, eclipse, jsp, warnings

I'm using Eclipse 3.7.2 on Windows 7 on a legacy Java webapp.

The webapp uses many JSP include files where a tag might be opened in that file, but closed in another.

For example, the file "header.jsp" has the "" tag, but the "footer.jsp" had the "" tag.
Eclipse gives a warning "No end tag" for that situation, though everything works.

Is there a way to make those warnings go away without turning off the JSP & HTML warnings and without rearranging my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rename them to .jspf files so they're considered JSP Fragments, then disable validation of fragments in the preferences.

Comment: Neat idea.  What does that do for me that just shutting off validation directly, for *.jsp and *.hmtl files will not?

Comment: It will ignore those files on their own while still processing them for the JSPs that include them.

Comment: Do you mean Eclipse will still run validations on *.jsp files while ignoring validation for .jspf?   I don't think my webapp has any 100% whole *.jsp files so maybe I am better off just tolerating or turning the validations for *.jsp files off

Comment: Yes, it will still validate HTML and JSP files, just not JSPF files.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on editor, go to Vaidation -> select Ignore
Hope it help !
[image]